# Will getting a new router speed up my WiFI?

Tags: wireless-networking

I got a notice from Xfinity that my speed had been increased from 600 Mbps to 800 Mbps so I checked my modem and realized that in only handled speeds of up to 300 Mbps so I just ordered a new one (a NETGEAR Gigabit Cable Modem (32x8) DOCSIS 3.1) that's supposed to handle up to 1 Gbps. So I'm expecting my wired connection to at least double, but now I'm wondering if my wireless router is fast enough. I have a TP-Link Archer C2600 and just saw the NETGEAR - Nighthawk RAX45 AX4300 Wi-Fi 6 Router that claims to be faster because it supports WiFi 6. But will my iPhone 11 and Dell laptop benefit from that? Seems like a new standard (beyond n and ac) that my existing hardware might not benefit from. I don't have a lot of connected devices so that's not an issue (2 iPhones, a Tivo, and my laptop) and I live in a relatively small apartment so the added range doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: Wifi maximum bandwidths depend on the devices you are connecting to it as well as the router. If you have an old device that doesn't support higher speeds then replacing the router will do nothing to improve speeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the product page of the TP-Link Archer C2600, it can handle up to 800Mbps over 2.4Ghz and 1733Mbps on the 5Ghz band.
So, you router doesn't need to be replaced.

You're upgrading your modem which is all you need to do, as it most certainly is the bottleneck at only 300Mbps.

https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c2600/